# Preconfigured REST API including authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I am an Android Developer. Every time I want to create an app, I need some kind of backend for it. In 99% of the cases there's a User registration envolved. So I wonder myself, if there isn't there a presetup django project somewhere, where all this user registration stuff is preconfigured allready? So I can checkout the project, add my models, add their visibility (in terms of "available for registrated users", "available for admins", a.s.o) and the project is good to go?!

With Userregistration I mean:

- A User can register via a REST interface, receives an email for confirming
- A User can login (TokenBased Authentication) after he confirmed this email
- A User can reset his email/password

I tried to do [something like that](https://github.com/Unic8/django-rest-api-template) by myself, but on some points it's just working a bit unexpected. (For those who are not familar with openshift, the django project is in the wsgi folder, called restapi)

I tried setting it up using [this docs](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). Changed a bit here and there, so that it contains like the main functionality I want.

Checkout the project using the develop branch (since I am using git-flow)

Here the behaviour:

- Registration: email is sent/displayed. When clicking on the email confirmation link it opens a white web page with a button to confirm. fine so far, except that the login redirect url, which is setup, does not redirect there.

settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'https://github.com/Unic8'
```

- Login works as expected successfully returns a valid token
- Reset Password unauthorized via email: This is kind of working as well, except that the base-url, used to build the validation link is taken from the one you setup in the admin interface "Sites". So after I logged into this, and changed "example.com" to "127.0.0.1:8000" it was building it correct as well. Don't get me wrong. its not wrong behaviour, but I expected django/plugins, to do it by themselfes, since the validation of the email on registering was doing it as well.

Could someone help me, getting rid of the confusions?
Does something like this maybe exists already and I am just too blind to find it?

Answer (score 0):

generaly :

1. everyone makes it's own integration of auth services, (as you're used to do) or
2. use facebook / google services, or
3. use stormpath provider that as a good integration with django:
   djongo stomrpath : https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-django
   https://stormpath.com/

(PS: I'm not a stormpath comercial ... :) ) enjoy

Comment: Looks interesting, but: 1. I believe I am almost there 2. I don't want to depend on another services 3. social login comes with "django-allauth" out of the box as well.